# How can an interaction design matrix be created from categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm coming from mainly working in R for statistical modeling / machine learning and looking to improve my skills in Python. I am wondering the best way to create a design matrix of categorical interactions (to arbitrary degree) in python.

A toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib import urlopen
page = urlopen("http://www.shatterline.com/MachineLearning/data/tennis_anyone.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(page)
df.head(n=5)
```

[image]

Lets say we want to create interactions between Outlook, Temp and Humidity. Is there an efficient way to do this? I can manually do something like this in pandas:

```
OutTempFact=pd.Series(pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.Outlook.values, df.Temperature.values]))[0],name='OutTemp')
OutHumFact=pd.Series(pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.Outlook.values, df.Humidity.values]))[0],name='OutHum')
TempHumFact=pd.Series(pd.factorize(pd.lib.fast_zip([df.Temperature.values, df.Humidity.values]))[0],name='TempHum')

IntFacts=pd.concat([OutTempFact,OutHumFact,TempHumFact],axis=1)
IntFacts.head(n=5)
```

[image]

which I could then pass to a scikit-learn one-hot encoder, but there is likely a much better, less manual way to create interactions between categorical variables without having to step through each combination.

```
import sklearn as sk
enc = sk.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
IntFacts_OH=enc.fit_transform(IntFacts)
IntFacts_OH.todense()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `OneHotEncoder` on your design matrix to obtain a one-hot design matrix, then interactions are nothing other than multiplications between columns. If `X_1hot` is your one-hot design matrix, where samples are lines, then for 2nd order interactions you can write

```
X_2nd_order = (X_1hot[:, np.newaxis, :] * X_1hot[:, :, np.newaxis]).reshape(len(X_1hot), -1)
```

There will be duplicates of interactions and it will contain the original features as well.

Going to arbitrary order is going to make your design matrix explode. If you really want to do that, then you should look into kernelizing with a polynomial kernel, which will let you go to arbitrary degrees easily.

Using the data frame you present, we can proceed as follows. First, a manual way to construct a one-hot design out of the data frame:

```
import numpy as np
indicators = []
state_names = []
for column_name in df.columns:
    column = df[column_name].values
    one_hot = (column[:, np.newaxis] == np.unique(column)).astype(float)
    indicators.append(one_hot)
    state_names = state_names + ["%s__%s" % (column_name, state) for state in np.unique(column)]

X_1hot = np.hstack(indicators)
```

The column names are then stored in `state_names` and the indicator matrix is `X_1hot`. Then we calculate the second order features

```
X_2nd_order = (X_1hot[:, np.newaxis, :] * X_1hot[:, :, np.newaxis]).reshape(len(X_1hot), -1)
```

In order to know the names of the columns of the second order matrix, we construct them like this

```
from itertools import product
one_hot_interaction_names = ["%s___%s" % (column1, column2) 
                             for column1, column2 in product(state_names, state_names)]
```

Comment: When I run on my toy example...I find some vectors have "3.". Are these the ones to flag as duplicates? Can you expand a bit for a novice on what this code is doing?

Comment: This is strange. The one-hot encoding I am referring to basically turns the design matrix into indicator functions for each category state, i.e. *Outlook* will become three columns *OutlookSunny*, *OutlookOvercast*, *OutlookRain*. Each line of the design matrix will contain a `1` in exactly one of those columns, and `0` in the other two. You do the same with the other categories and end up with a wide matrix full of many `0` and a few `1`s. The operation I wrote in my answer takes each line of the design matrix and calculates the outer product with itself.

Comment: The outer product in this case being the matrix of all possible products of all feature entries of that sample. Since the sample lines can only take values `0` and `1`, the outer product results can only be matrices with `0` and `1` content. The reshape operation ravels the interaction matrix into a long vector and thus the whole operation creates an augmented one-hot design matrix where the indicators are on pairs of category states. Since every state pair is doubly represented in the matrix, it will be doubly represented in the raveled vector.

Comment: You can copy and paste the updated example. `X_1hot` contains indicators for all the states and `X_2nd_order` contains the indicators for all interactions. The names of the interactions are in `one_hot_interaction_names`. Please let me know if this is actually what you were intending to obtain :)

Comment: Thanks! I need to study this to understand it. I do note that the odd result with values of 3 result if you use IntFacts_OH.todense() in the X_2nd_order function.

Comment: Actually, this is due to the fact that `IntFacts_OH.todense()` is of type `np.matrix`, not `np.array` and behaves differently when used with the `*` operator. If you use `IntFacts_OH.toarray()`, this should work just fine. Most people avoid `np.matrix` precisely because of this unexpected behaviour, especially if working with more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Being now faced with a similar problem of wanting an easy way of integrating specific interactions from a baseline OLS model from the literature to compare against ML appraches, I came across *patsy* (http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) and this scikit-learn integration *patsylearn* (https://github.com/amueller/patsylearn).

Below, how the interaction variables could be passed to the model:

```
from patsylearn import PatsyModel
model = PatsyModel(sk.linear_model.LinearRegression(), "Play-Tennis ~ C(Outlook):C(Temperature) + C(Outlook):C(Humidity) + C(Outlook):C(Wind)")
```

Note, that in this formulation you don't need the OneHotEncoder(), as the C in the formula tells the Patsy interpreter that these are categorical variables and they are one-hot encoded for you! But read more about it in their documentation (http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html).

Or, you could also use the PatsyTransformer, which I prefer, as it allows easy integration into scikit-learn Pipelines:

```
from patsylearn import PatsyTransformer
transformer = PatsyTransformer("C(Outlook):C(Temperature) + C(Outlook):C(Humidity) + C(Outlook):C(Wind)")
```