# One hot encoding multi dimensional data

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, keras

Using code below I'm attempting to one hot code multi dimensional data. In this case the data is 2d. The code works as expected for 1d data but for 2d data each column is one hot encoded instead of the entire row. For example : for first data point `[9,8]` instead of a single one hot encoded data point being generated two data points are generated each corresponding to 9 & 8 respectively.

How can I one hot encode multi dimensional data ?

2dim.csv :

```
x_1,x_2
9,8
2,3
4,3
120,3
4,3
1,89
2,6
3,3
```

Code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd

inputValues = pd.read_csv('2dim.csv')

enc = inputValues.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
cat = np_utils.to_categorical(enc , 20)

inputValues :
```

[image]

```
cat :
```

[image]

`cat` should contain 9 one hot encoded data points instead of 18.

Is a possible solution to this combine every 2 adjoining inner arrays ? , for example `array([[1...n_1],[2...n_2],[3...n_3],[4...n_4]])` is mapped to `array([[1...n_1,2...n_2],[3...n_3,4...n_4]])`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23497512/8201433) post. It explains how one hot encoding could be obtained over two features

Comment: @Sriram thanks for link. One hot encoding is such a common operation for multi dimensional data that I would have thought there is a simple function call based on pandas and/or scikit-learn. Solution contained in link you referenced is not overly complicated but more complicated than I expected. Keras makes it straightforward to prototype a deep learning model , it's strange that same principle does not exist for one hot encoding or am I not understanding something ?

Answer (score -1):

try: `pd.get_dummies(inputValues)` [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)